# Google Forms Submit and Return to a page within the form

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to get my Google form to return to a page within the form after submitting.  This is a payroll form in which there are 5 locations in which each of the managers will choose there location first.  The form then points them to the appropriate page with the appropriate employees in a drop down etc...

The problem is that once they submit an employees time for the day, the form takes them back to the launch page instead of back to their location page.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this tutorial will work, it's more of a hack and I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this, http://www.immersionmedia.com/blog/customizing-and-styling-google-forms/

This tutorial tells you what code to extract from the form. There are other, better ways to do this that involve validating each of your quiz elements (text box, multiple choice etc), but I don't know how to do this. If you find out a better way than my suggestion, please post here.

Hope this helps